# SUMIFS Function in Excel returning "too many arguments"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I encountered the "too many arguments" error when trying to calculate the total sum of values from column C if the following criteria are met:

When F is equals B

When E is larger or equals to D (to minus 1 from current year and keep month and day from D)

When E smaller or equals to D (to get current year as well as month and day from D)

(where E and D are dates, F and B are employee code)

Formula as follows:

`=SUMIFS(C:C,F:F,B3,E:E,">="&DATE(YEAR(EDATE(TODAY(),-12)),MONTH(D3),DAY(D3)),E:E,"<="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY(),MONTH(D3)),DAY(D3)))`

Does anyone know of a work around?

Thank You!

Comment: Did you check the [**documentation**](https://support.office.com/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) for the function?

Comment: Your final criteria argument `DATE(YEAR(TODAY(),MONTH(D3)),DAY(D3))` has several syntactical errors.  Correct them and you should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

You misplaced a bracket.

```
=SUMIFS(C:C, F:F, B3, E:E,">="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-1, MONTH(D3), DAY(D3)), E:E, "<="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(D3), DAY(D3)))
```

No need for edate.